# How do I convert URL in a plain text to clickable links using python?

Tags: python, html, regex, url

I have plain text, for example, take into account the following sentence :

> I was surfing www.google.com and I found an interesting site [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com). It's amazing!

In above example, www.google.com is a plain text, which I need to be converted like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (wrapped within anchor tag, having link to google.com). While, www.stackoverflow.com is already within anchor tag, which I want to keep intact. How can I do this using Python regular-expression ?

Comment: Using a HTML parser would be a far superior solution. Regexes are not suited to such job!

Comment: @Docteur Can you provide some easy "how-to"s examples which substitutes text using HTML parser ? Thank you so much ! :)

Answer (score 2):

This task has to be splitted into two parts:

- extract all text which is not already in `a` tag
- find (or better say guess) all urls in that text and wrap them

For the first part, I recommend to go with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You could also use [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/html.parser.html#example-html-parser-application), but that would be a lot of extra work

Use a recursive function for finding the text:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString

your_text = """I was surfing <a href="...">www.google.com</a>, and I found an
interesting site https://www.stackoverflow.com/. It's amazing! I also liked
Heroku (http://heroku.com/pricing)
more.domains.tld/at-the-end-of-line
https://at-the_end_of-text.com"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_text, "html.parser")

def wrap_plaintext_links(bs_tag):
    for element in bs_tag.children:
        if type(element) == NavigableString:
            pass # now we have a text node, process it
        # so it is a Tag (or the soup object, which is for most purposes a tag as well)
        elif element.name != "a": # if it isn't the a tag, process it recursively
            wrap_plaintext_links(element)

wrap_plaintext_links(soup) # call the recursive function
```

You can test it finds only the values you want by replacing `pass` with `print(element)`.

---

Now the finding urls and replacing itself. The complexity of the used regular expression really depends on how precise do you want to be. I would go with this:

```
(https?://)?        # match http(s):// in separate group if present
(                   # start of the main capturing group, what will be between the tags
  (?:[\w-]+\.)+     #   at least one domain and any subdomains before TLD
  [a-z]+            #   TLD
  (?:/\S*?)?        #   /[anything except whitespace] if present - URL path
)                   # end of the group
(?=[\.,)]?(?:\s|$)) # prevent matching any of ".,)" that might appear immediately after the URL as the text goes...
```

The function and code additions including replacing:

```py
import re

def create_replacement(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1): # if there's http(s)://, keep it
        full_url = matchobj.group(0)
    else: # otherwise prepend it. it would be a long discussion if https or http. decide.
        full_url = "http://" + matchobj.group(2)
    tag = soup.new_tag("a", href=full_url)
    tag.string = matchobj.group(2)
    return str(tag)

# compile the pattern beforehand, as it's going to be used many times
r = re.compile(r"(https?://)?((?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]+(?:/\S*?)?)(?=[\.,)]?(?:\s|$))")

def wrap_plaintext_links(bs_tag):
    for element in bs_tag.children:
        if type(element) == NavigableString:
            replaced = r.sub(create_replacement, str(element))
            element.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(replaced)) # make it a Soup so that the tags aren't escaped
        elif element.name != "a":
            wrap_plaintext_links(element)
```

*Note: you can also include the pattern explanation in the code as I wrote it above, see the [`re.X`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.X) flag*